# Frequency of vectors-vectors in matrix

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have the following in 12x3 matrix

```
m<-rbind(c(0,7,0),c(1,1,5),c(6,1,1),c(1,3,-3),c(1,3,-3),c(1,1,5),
c(0,7,0),c(1,1,5),c(1,1,5),-c(0,7,0),c(1,1,5),c(1,3,-3))
```

and would like count the number of times each row-vector occurs. What do I do?

I have tried to use `table()`, but `table()` only counts the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert each row to a concatenated string and then use table.

```
m <- apply(m, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))
table(m)

m

0 -7 0  0 7 0  1 1 5 1 3 -3  6 1 1 
     1      2      5      3      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that keeps the source data as columns. It uses the `.N` function from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(m)[, .N, by = eval(paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(m))))]
#    V1 V2 V3 N
# 1:  0  7  0 2
# 2:  1  1  5 5
# 3:  6  1  1 1
# 4:  1  3 -3 3
# 5:  0 -7  0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or convert to `data.frame` and use `do.call(paste`

```
 table(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m)))

 #0 -7 0  0 7 0  1 1 5 1 3 -3  6 1 1 
 #    1      2      5      3      1
```

Or use `sprintf`

```
 table(do.call(sprintf, c(as.data.frame(m), '%d %d %d')))
```